# Array for_each in QGIS

Tags: qgis, expression, array, transform

Is there an expression in QGIS for `array for_each` to get the element from the output of `geom_to_wkt($geometry)` of the polygon and correspondingly transform  the element (using the expression of LAT LONG Tool) from decdeg to ddmmss?
i.e.
array input:

```
51.06993546 25.58704192, 51.13739268 25.60501474, 51.15957073 25.54595078
```

desired output:

```
253513.35N 0510411.77E -
253618.05N 0510814.61E -
253245.42N 0510934.45E.
```

Answer (score 5):

**Edit**

New expression for your desired output in degrees, minutes, seconds but without delimiter symbols (older solution below).

What you want to do indeed need installation of [Lat Lon Tools plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/latlontools/): this adds a new funtion to the expression editor: `ddmmss`. If you have a geometry with vertices `51.06993546 25.58704192, 51.13739268 25.60501474, 51.15957073 25.54595078`, you can use the follwoging expression to get this output (coordinates for all vertices, from first to last) in string format, including line breaks. Simply switch `xy` to `yx` to change between lon/lat and lat/lon:

```
253513.35N 0510411.77E
253618.05N 0510814.61E
253245.42N 0510934.45E
```

```
replace (
    array_to_string (
        array_foreach (
            generate_series (1, num_points( $geometry)-1),
            right (ddmmss (y(point_n ($geometry,@element)), x (point_n ($geometry,@element)),'xy',2), 10)  || ' ' || 
            left (ddmmss (y(point_n ($geometry,@element)), x (point_n ($geometry,@element)),'xy',2), 11)  || '\n'
    )),
    ',',''
)
```

**First solution**

Use the function `to_dms` to convert coordinates to *degree, minute, second* format. If you have a geometry with vertices `51.06993546 25.58704192, 51.13739268 25.60501474, 51.15957073 25.54595078`, you can use the follwoging expression to get this output (coordinates for all vertices, from first to last) in string format:

```
51°4′11.77″N 25°35′13.35″E,51°8′14.61″N 25°36′18.05″E,51°9′34.45″N 25°32′45.42″E
```

The expression:

```
array_to_string (
    array_foreach (
        generate_series (1, num_points( $geometry)-1),
        to_dms (x(point_n( $geometry,@element)),'y',2, 'suffix')  || ' ' || 
        to_dms(y(point_n( $geometry,@element)),'x',2, 'suffix') 
))
```

**Variants:**

- To get a line break after each coordinates pair, add  `|| '\n'` at the end of the second last line.
- To delete commas from the output, add `replace (` at the very beginning of the expression and `,',','')` at the very end.

```
replace (
    array_to_string (
        array_foreach (
            generate_series (1, num_points( $geometry)-1),
            to_dms (x(point_n( $geometry,@element)),'y',2, 'suffix')  || ' ' || 
            to_dms(y(point_n( $geometry,@element)),'x',2, 'suffix')  || '\n'
    )),
    ',',''
)
```

With this expression, you get the following output (including line breaks):

```
51°4′11.77″N 25°35′13.35″E
51°8′14.61″N 25°36′18.05″E
51°9′34.45″N 25°32′45.42″E
```

Comment: Thanks Babel for the reply! Just a follow up, is there a way to present it in LAT-LONG  instead of LONG-LAT and without the symbols i.e. 253513.35N 0510411.77E?

Comment: For `lat/lon` instead of `lon/lat`, simply change `x` and `y` in the expression (line 4 and 5). You should not use these values without the symbols as this is not correct as it looks like a numer with 6 decimals before and two after the point. If you still want to do it, use the second expression (the one including `replace`) and replace the second last line ( `',',''` ) with this: `array (',','°','′','″'),''`

Comment: Is there a way to use the Lat Lon Tools expression inside the array foreach?  i.e. ddmmss(('y(point_n( $geometry,@element))' ,'x(point_n( $geometry,@element))', 'yx', 2, ' '), I can't seem to figure out how or it's not possible.

Comment: What do you mean by "Lat Lon Tools" - this plugin? https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/latlontools/ - You can't use a plugin inside an expression, if that is the question.

Comment: You mean to say even though it has a corresponding expression in the field calculator? it cannot be used? Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: In the plugins window for Lat Lon Tools it states that: "Conversion functions for the field calculator"

Comment: OK, I have to admit that I do not know the plugin and what it exactly does. It might be that it adds custom functions to be used with expressions?

Comment: From what I gather the pluggin can reformat the decDeg to ddmmss.ss with expression ddmmmss("y", "x", 'yx', 2, ' ') where y and x are columns thus the output will be in the manner as 253513.35N 0510411.77E. Somehow I cannot adapt it the your array foreach expression.

Comment: Installed the plugin, I see what you mean. Hope now it works for you: see updated answer.

Comment: Hi Babel, you got the hemispheres incorrectly in your code, you call the x point but assign the y coordinate so you are mixing them up, which I think is what confuses Roel

Comment: @Antonio Locandro : indeed, thanks for the hint! I adapted the expression now so that the output is exactly what ROEL SANTIAGO is looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Based on Babel's initial response this is the expression that provides the required output. You will notice I used ***regexp_replace*** to remove the degrees. minutes and seconds part.

Also since I am assuming you are in a location where your longitude is less than 100 you can hardcode the 0 as the lead, if not you will need to add a case statement to check if is less or more and apply the according format.

In your case you do not want to use 'suffix' but 'aligned' in order to get leading zero/padding for the minutes and seconds

regexp_replace(replace (
array_to_string (
array_foreach (
generate_series (1, num_points( $geometry)-1),
to_dms (y(point_n( $geometry,@element)),'y',2, 'aligned')  || ' 0' ||
to_dms(x(point_n( $geometry,@element)),'x',2, 'aligned')  || '\n'
)),
',','- '
),'°|′|″','')

This is how it looks in the table

[image]

I recommend watching this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8rOe-9A84O8 if you may want to implement what you are doing into an action as I am guessing this is not really for the attribute table that you need it